# How to sketch a differential form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I deal with differential geometry for a while now but still don't have a intuitional graphical understanding for differential forms, more precisely 1-forms.

For example, how to sketch the 1-form $dx$?

Also, I don't understand this example from wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_geometry#/media/File:Standard_contact_structure.svg

I try different approaches to understand this,

1. using the curve-definition of tangent vectors
2. using the definition as maps $C^{\infty}(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

but I still don't understand.

Can somebody help me here and give a hint, which definition is better to use to understand sketches of 1-forms?

Comment: What's the problem with sketching a 1-form as a vector field?

Comment: @PeterWildemann Because you have to choose a metric tensor for this first.

Comment: The example from wikipedia you are referring too isn't sketching a 1-form, but only its kernel, which is a certain plane at every point.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I still do not completely understand the picture: Why is the kernel a plane at every point?

Comment: In this particular case, the differential form $\alpha$ is nonvanishing hence its kernel at every point is not the whole tangent space, so it must have dimension two ($\alpha_p$ is like a full-rank map $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Ok so for example, on each point on the x-axis, $dz(v)$ has to be zero and this space is spanned by $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$, correct?